# import ImageTk for google earth engine

Tags: python-imaging-library, google-earth-engine

I want to import `ee.mapclient`

but when I do this the following error is returned:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-16-5f312fd5c732>", line 1, in <module>
    import ee.mapclient

  File "C:\Users\Stefano\Anaconda2_2\lib\site-packages\ee\mapclient.py", line 43, in <module>
    import ImageTk             # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top

ImportError: No module named ImageTk
```

I am using anaconda and have installed pillow and PIL.  Within my PIL folder in `site-packages` there is a file caled `ImageTk`.

When I do this:

`from PIL import Image, ImageTk`

everything imports fine, but for some reason `ee.mapclient` is not recognizing this.

A link to the python code used in `mapclient.py` can be found here:
https://github.com/google/earthengine-api/blob/master/python/ee/mapclient.py

Comment: Could it be a versioning issue? Feels like one to me. Which version of Anaconda/Python are you using?

Comment: I am using python 2.7 and anaconda 4.1.1

Comment: Also, I inserted `from PIL import Image, ImageTk` into the `mapclient.py` code and it doesn't return the import error anymore, but it also doesn't seem to work.

Comment: After doing some light research, I get the impression this might be a OS-related issue. I tried it on Windows as well and `tk` keeps crashing. A couple of the EE guys (in the google group EE developers) mentioned that `mapclient` tends to only work on Linux but that for both Windows and Linux the versions of the `Tk library` are buggy in their own way and that it behaves differently on different machines. Granted, some of these posts are a couple of years old but I'm haven't read anything about a resolution of these issues. So maybe you can get by with a workaround or try contacting a dev.

Answer (score 0):

Edit mapclient to put "from PIL import Image,ImageTk " in try block ,